# Apply scale/rotation - shrinks mesh/rotates mesh 2.8

Tags: mesh, rigging, transforms

I'm completely new to Blender and am trying to rig a friends model he created awhile ago. I've got a tiny bit of experience rigging in Maya and 3ds Max and I think that the reason I'm having the issue is because my meshes scale and rotation isn't freezing/applying.

When I imported the model I scaled it up to the right size and rotated it for the same reason.

I've tried applying all transforms to delta, setting origin to 3D cursor and all the various "apply location etc" it just always reverts back to the tiny size and wrong rotation.

What am I missing/doing wrong? please help, thanks. Two screenshots below show before and after applying "apply transforms" NOTE: this is in 2.8 latest version.

[image: Before applying transforms]

[image: After applying transforms]

Comment: How did you apply transforms? your first screenshot shows values of an already applied transforms (loc 0,0,0, rot 0,0,0, scale 1,1,1) and dimensions tipycal of humans (1.92 tall). Anyway the correct method is to select the object in object mode, reset its delta transforms (0,0,0-0,0,0-1,1,1), move rotate and scale as wanted, then press Ctrl A and choose apply All transforms (or rotation and scale, if you want to retain the object origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset Delta transforms to default values before other operations. Then you can move, rotate scale the model in object mode as you want; then press Ctrl A and choose Apply All Transform.

[image]

Comment: You genius, thanks a lot. I'm not sure why that's a thing but I'm sure there's a good reason. Thanks again.

Comment: I also never used delta transform :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not get your question right, but Ive made a test with Suzanne (Monkey Head), I scaled it up, and rotate it in X axis (in Object Mode), then I go to the Object tab in the viewport, and Apply all transforms. The Head is still at the size I resized, Location, Rotation is set to 0 and Scale to 1.

You mean that in your case, while your applying transformation, the model get back to the original size ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying and yes that's what I did. I scaled it up and rotated it in object mode, then went to the viewports object tab and applied all transforms and it shrunk back down and rotated back to the original.